# Is a Bernoulli process a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

For a Bernoulli process, the outcome of a future trial is independent of the outcome of past trials. I.e., the future behaviour of a Bernoulli process is independent of its past, i.e. a Bernoulli process posesses the Markov property. So every Bernoulli trial is a Markov chain, right?

Comment: Every process made of i.i.d. random variables is a homogenous  Markov chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see [Breuer 2005 p. 2](http://meyer.math.ncsu.edu/Meyer/Courses/HuiXie_591R_MarkovChains.pdf)

---

References:

Breuer, L. and D. Baum (2005). An Introduction to Queueing Theory: And Matrix-Analytic Methods, Springer.

Comment: If we know the transition matrix theory then we could say a Bernoulli process of parameter p has a free parameter namely the average length of equal results series.

Comment: Original link does not work anymore. Wayback link: https://web.archive.org/web/20100614095319/https://meyer.math.ncsu.edu/Meyer/Courses/HuiXie_591R_MarkovChains.pdf